# App appearing in search but not the shared posts

Tags: facebook, search, permissions

My app is now finally appearing in Facebook's search, hooray.

However none of the activity associated with my app such as when people have shared content from my app, liked something and posted it to their wall etc is appearing in the search.

I am requesting publish_actions, email and user_likes in the permissions when someone logs in to my app, so I thought this would enable me to see or search when someone has posted or shared something from my app.

Is anyone able to offer any advice on this? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: It will show up in the users' activity log, and once the app has acquired enough traction and has gotten enough interest, it will also show up on news feeds.

Comment: Thanks deesarus. Will just have to keep waiting. Was confused as the app itself is showing up in searches - so assumed we had reached the right criteria.